# Python for loop break on the last iteration using slicing

Tags: python, for-loop, slice

I'm trying to loop over a list and print this list each time but only print 'next' on all but the last iteration. I've tried a number of different ideas without much luck. Below is an example that is close to what I want but still prints 'next' because my if statement doesn't seem to break. Is there a way to do my comparison statement using slicing like I'm trying? Is there a better way to go about this? Thanks.

```
chapters = ['one', 'two', 'three',]

for x in chapters:
    print x
    if x == chapters[:-1]:
        break
    else:
        print 'next'

result:
one
next
two
next
three
next (<--I don't want this one)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
chapters = ['one', 'two', 'three',]

for x in chapters:
    print x
    if x != chapters[-1]:
        print 'next'
```

Alternatively you can also do:

```
for x in chapters:
    print x
    if x == chapters[-1]:
       break
    print 'next'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was so close. It's always the little things isn't it. ...Walks off to go read up on slicing again.

Answer (score 0):

Your slicing is wrong. If you want to test if `x` is the last element, you need to use `[-1]`

```
>>>chapters = ['one', 'two', 'three',]
>>>for x in chapters:
>>>    print x
>>>    if x == chapters[-1]:
>>>        break
>>>    else:
>>>        print 'next'
one
next
two
next
three
```

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
chapters = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for x in chapters:
   print x
   if x == chapters[-1]:
      break
   else:
      print 'next'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in chapters[:-1]:
    print x, '\nnext'
print chapters[-1]
```

or you can use `join`:

```
print '\nnext\n'.join(chapters)
# '\nnext\n' is equal to '\n'+'next'+'\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

```
chapters = ['one', 'two', 'three']
length = len(chapters) - 1
for i, x in enumerate(chapters):
    print x
    if i < length:
        print 'next'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that keeps with the general idea you had:

```
chapters = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for x in chapters:
    if x != chapters[-1]:
        print x, '\nnext'
    else:
        print x
```

The issue with your slicing is that the slice you had down,

```
chapters[:-1]
```

is actually the following list,

```
['one', 'two']
```

and your code is comparing each individual chapter value to this list. So, the comparison is basically doing something like this:

```
'one' == ['one', 'two']
```

Which would evaluate to false.